# Bukkit - Get Variables From Other @EventHandlers?

Tags: java, bukkit

I was wondering how I would get a variable from a different @EventHandler. My variable in this instance is an array list.

My code is below:

```
@EventHandler
public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event) {
    ArrayList<String> build = new ArrayList();
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if(!player.isOp()) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }else if(!build.contains(player)) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }else if(build.contains(player)) {
        event.setCancelled(false);
    }
}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    event.setJoinMessage("§4§l>>§a§l " + player + " §b§ljoined! §4§l<<");
    if(build.contains(player)) {
        build.remove(player);
```

Now, on the second @EventHandler it cannot resolve the variable "build" which is what I defined in the previous @EventHandler. So how can I make it so it works?

Comment: The issue is variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

`build` is a local variable and is only available within the method `onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event)`.

What you want to do is declare a variable outside the method and initialize it in it's `onEnable()` method. You should also do what KingFaris10 metioned and store the player's UUID. You will also need someway to add the players to the ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<UUID> build;
@Override
public void onEnable () {
    build = new ArrayList<UUID>();
}

@EventHandler
public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    //Following derived from KingFaris10
    if (!player.isOp() || !build.contains(player.getUUID())) event.setCancelled(true);
    else event.setCancelled(false);
}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    event.setJoinMessage("§4§l>>§a§l " + player + " §b§ljoined! §4§l<<");
    UUID id = player.getUUID();
    if(build.contains(id)) {
        build.remove(id);
```